# Inheritance from template: correct constructor

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

When inheriting from a template in child class constructor is it necessary at a call of the parent constructor to specify template parameter.
Code example:

```
    template<typename TYPE>
class Association
{
public:
    Association(TYPE* object) : m_object(object) {}
private:
    TYPE* m_object;
};

class MyClass
{
};

class AssociationToMyClass : public Association<MyClass>
{
    // is the constructor correct
    AssociationToMyClass(MyClass* object) : Association<MyClass>(object) {}
    // or this one?
    AssociationToMyClass(MyClass* object) : Association(object) {}
};
```

Comment: Both are correct in current example. The first one would be required in case of multiple inheritance (of `Association`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.  `Association<MyClass>` is more explicit, but there's an "injected class name" visible for name lookup where `Association` means the same as `Association<MyClass>`.